# own cutting planes for LP relaxation in Gurobi

Tags: java, gurobi

I am currently working with Gurobi by implementing in Java using the Gurobi Java interface. I want to accelerate the solving process of certain MIPs by implementing a callback function that generates my own cutting planes. These cutting planes should be generated in every node of the branch-and-bound tree to tighten the corresponding LP-relaxation of the node. Therefore I need optimal solution variables of the LP-relaxation. At the moment I don't know how to set the WHERE and WHAT variables of the callback function to get the optimal solution variables of the LP-relaxation in a node.
The following [Gurobi page](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/callback_codes.html) has more informations and it looks to me that Gurobi only offers in C the excess of the solution variables of the LP-relaxation.
Thanks for every answer...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/examples/callback_java.html) example? It is possible with the Python API and I guess [this](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/java_grbcallback_getnodere.html) is the equivalent Java method.